# Pakcage "apache' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, apache2

I'm trying to install Apache into Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1, but retrieving the error: ***package apache2 has no installation candidate***
Any help, please? Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this command could help you:

```
echo 'deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt update && sudo apt install apache2
```

This command adds [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/apache2/download) which contains package apache2 for ubuntu 18.04, updates your source list and installs apache2.